# Connecting to a computer inside a network

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, sockets, dmz

I have a network in my College which is connected to the internet. How can I access a system inside this network from the internet (WAN)? I don't have access to the gateway of the system, so port forwarding is not an option. Is there any program that could run inside my computer (which is in the network) that could then connect to a static IP address on the Internet, reverse the connection, and make me able to use `ssh/telnet` to access the computer?

Edit:
I checked the duplicate question but still I am little bit confused.
Actually in my college I have ssh non root access to a system (192.168.1.5) from within the network

Is there anyway I can access that machine through ssh from the internet?

If ssh tunneling is an option how to setup that?

Can anybody explain step by step?

Comment: What operating systems are on these computers? (Inside the network and outside)

Comment: If your not able to port forward you won't be able to access the network from the internet.

Comment: If the system that you are trying to connect to from the world wide web is on your own computer, you will have to sustain a connection with a service (on the web) through a program on your computer. I; however, do not know of a program that might do this. You might look at `proxy servers` and Dropbox-like services that allow you to receive information from the web (or a proxy server) simultaneously with its input. Good luck to ya.

Comment: @Ramhound That's not necessarily true. See my post above.

Comment: The user doesn't have the ability to run a proxy server within the college's network.

Comment: You can set up a reverse tunnel to your home, or a VPN. Then you can connect from an arbitrary place to your home, and from there to your college. Alternatively, you can buy a cheap VM from a commercial provider, and use that instead of your home.

Comment: @Ramhound I had never said running the proxy from his college network. The proxy would be outside of his network, and he would connect to it using a "dropbox-like service."